# Overriding Devise::RegistratoinsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So I am trying to override Devise::RegistrationsController which they do have wiki for and tons of tutorial out there. The one thing that I can not find is the best implementation of how to override the controller whilst implementing the require admin approval feature as well.

I think I got the hang of it but before I go any further (from all the reading on the Devise's source code) I want to know, on the registrations controller there's a line that does:

```
resource.active_for_authentication?
```

However, on the Sessions controller it's just this:

```
def create
self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
sign_in(resource_name, resource)
yield resource if block_given?
respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

What I want to know is, if it's not confirmed or the active_for_authentication returns false, where or how does the session controller check this? I tried tracing back the source code but no luck.

So anyone who's very familiar with Devise perhaps you could answer my question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After authenticating a user and in each request, Devise checks if your model is active by calling model.active_for_authentication?. This method is overwritten by other devise modules. For instance, :confirmable overwrites .active_for_authentication? to only return true if your model was confirmed.

You can overwrite this method yourself, but if you do, don't forget to call super:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && special_condition_is_valid?
end
```

Whenever active_for_authentication? returns false, Devise asks the reason why your model is inactive using the inactive_message method. You can overwrite it as well:

```
def inactive_message
  special_condition_is_valid? ? super : :special_condition_is_not_valid
end
```